# getting "AccountBeforeTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001"

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to update a field with just four of our accounts as initial testing to the final 25000 records to be update. However, I'm getting "AccountBeforeTrigger: System.LimitException: Too many query rows: 50001
"

//The original owner of the code already out of the company. Please help.

**Trigger Code**

```
trigger AccountBeforeTrigger on Account(before insert, before update) {
    Map < string, string > territoryMap = new Map < string, string > ();
    Map < string, string > territotyRevMap = new Map < string, string > ();
    staticResource resource = new staticresource();
    List < Account > listOfAccounts = new List < Account > ();
    List < Account > accListSAMS = new List < Account > ();
    List < Account > accountListSAMS = new List < Account > ();
    List < Account > accountListSAMSForSubProducer = new List < Account > ();
    Set < String > CampaignCodes = new Set < String > ();
    set < String > uniqueNationalId = new set < String > ();

    List < Occupation_Description_SAMS__c > occupationCodeList = Occupation_Description_SAMS__c.getAll().values();

    List < Account > accountListSAMSForAddressId = new List < Account > ();
    List < Account > accountListSAMSForPhoneId = new List < Account > ();
    List < Account > accountListSAMSForRemarksId = new List < Account > ();
    List < Account > accountListSAMSForBiodataId = new List < Account > ();
    List < Account > accountListSAMSForAddressPhoneBiodataId = new List < Account > ();
    List < HOD_Target_SAMS__c > lstAgentTraget = new List < HOD_Target_SAMS__c > ();
    Map < String, string > mapOfValueCode = new Map < String, string > ();

    Map < String, string > mapOfCodeValue = new Map < String, string > ();
    Map < String, string > mapOfAgentGroupcode = new Map < String, string > ();

    for (Group_Code_SAMS__c groupcode: [select Group_Code_External_Field__c, Agent_Name_Backend_Field__c from Group_Code_SAMS__c]) {

        mapOfAgentGroupcode.put(groupcode.Agent_Name_Backend_Field__c, groupcode.Group_Code_External_Field__c);

    }
    system.debug(mapOfAgentGroupcode);

    List < RecordType > RecordTypeIDVar = new List < RecordType > ([SELECT ID, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType = 'Account'
        AND DeveloperName = 'Agent_Broker'
        AND IsPersonType = True
    ]);
    Id recordType = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Corporate Producer SAMS'
        limit 1
    ].Id;
    //Id recordType1 = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'SAMS_Intermediate Sub Producer' limit 1].Id;
    //Id CorporateAgent = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'SAMS Corporate Producer' limit 1].Id;     
    Id subproducer = [SELECT Id, Name FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'Sub Producer SAMS Agent'
        limit 1
    ].Id;
    //Id CorporateAgent = [SELECT Id,Name FROM RecordType WHERE Name = 'SAMS Corporate Producer' limit 1].Id;   
    Id AgentRec = [select id, Name from RecordType where Name = 'SAMS Agents'
        limit 1
    ].id;

    User userCheckForRole = [select UserRole.DeveloperName from User where Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
    //Add for AIG TH SAMS checking that user who logging is SAMS user or not

    for (Account acc: Trigger.New) {

        if (acc.RecordTypeId == AgentRec) {

            for (Group_Code_SAMS__c groupcode: [select Group_Code_External_Field__c, Agent_Name_Backend_Field__c from Group_Code_SAMS__c]) {

                mapOfAgentGroupcode.put(groupcode.Agent_Name_Backend_Field__c, groupcode.Group_Code_External_Field__c);

            }

            /* for(Occupation_Description_SAMS__c occupation : occupationCodeList){
                 mapOfValueCode.put(occupation.Occupation_Description__c,occupation.Occupation_Code__c);
                 mapOfCodeValue.put(occupation.Occupation_Code__c,occupation.Occupation_Description__c);
             }*/
            if (acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c != Null) {
                if (mapOfValueCode.containsKey(acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c))
                    acc.Primary_Occupation_Code_SAMS__c = mapOfValueCode.get(acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c);
                if (mapOfCodeValue.containsKey(acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c)) {
                    acc.Primary_Occupation_Code_SAMS__c = acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c;
                    acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c = mapOfCodeValue.get(acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c);
                }
            }

            if (acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c == Null) {
                acc.Primary_Occupation_Code_SAMS__c = null;
            }

            if (acc.Primary_Occupation_SAMS__c == Null) {
                acc.Primary_Occupation_Code_SAMS__c = null;
            }
            if (acc.isConvertedfromLead_SAMS__c == false) {
                for (Account accAll: [select Id_number__c from Account where(RecordTypeId = : recordType OR RecordTypeId = : subproducer OR RecordTypeId = : AgentRec) and Id_number__c != null]) {
                    uniqueNationalId.add(accAll.Id_number__c);
                }
            }
        }



        if (Trigger.isInsert) {
            //accListSAMS.add(acc);
            if (acc.PersonEmail != Null) {
                acc.Email_Buisness_SAMS__c = acc.PersonEmail;
            }
            if (uniqueNationalId.contains(acc.Id_number__c) && acc.id_number__c != null) {
                acc.addError('The National Id for this Agent is already existis / Duplicate National Id.');


            }

            // copy the first 40 character(13/8/2015)

            if ((acc.First_Full_Name__c != NULL && acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() <= 40) || acc.First_Full_Name__c == NULL) {
                if (acc.First_Full_Name__c == NULL && acc.FirstName != NULL) {
                    // 
                    acc.First_Full_Name__c = acc.FirstName;

                } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c != NULL && acc.FirstName == NULL) {
                    acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c;

                } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c != NULL && acc.FirstName != NULL) {
                    if (acc.First_Full_Name__c != acc.FirstName)
                        acc.addError('First Full Name and First Name Cannont be different as both are under 40 Characters');

                }


            } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c != NULL && acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() > 40) {
                if (acc.FirstName == NULL) {
                    acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c.subString(0, 40);
                } else if (acc.FirstName != NULL) {
                    if (acc.FirstName.length() != 40) {
                        acc.addError('First Full Name is Greater than 40 characters so first name must be atleast 40 characters');
                    } else if (acc.FirstName.length() == 40) {
                        if (acc.FirstName != acc.First_Full_Name__c.subString(0, 40)) {
                            acc.addError('First 40 Characters of First Full Name and first name must be same');

                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            // Addition ends(13/8/2015)
            /*if(acc.First_Full_Name__c.length()> 40) 
                                  acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c.subString(0,40);*/
            if (acc.Agency_Manager_SAMS__c != NULL) {
                acc.OwnerId = acc.Agency_Manager_SAMS__c;
            }
            /* if(acc.RecordTypeID == subproducer ){
                 accountListSAMSForSubProducer.add(acc);
             }*/
            //if(acc.RecordTypeId == AgentRec || acc.RecordTypeId == subproducer ){
            if (acc.Remarks_SAMS__c != NULL) {
                acc.Remarks_SAMS__c = acc.Remarks_SAMS__c.replace('\r\n', ' ');
                acc.Remarks_SAMS__c = acc.Remarks_SAMS__c.replace('\n', ' ');
                acc.Remarks_SAMS__c = acc.Remarks_SAMS__c.replace('\r', ' ');
            }
            if (acc.AddressId_SAMS__c == NULL)
                accountListSAMSForAddressId.add(acc);

            if (acc.PhoneId_SAMS__c == NULL)
                accountListSAMSForPhoneId.add(acc);

            if (acc.Biodata_Id_SAMS__c == NULL)
                accountListSAMSForBiodataId.add(acc);

            if (acc.Remark_Id_SAMS__c == NULL)

                accountListSAMSForRemarksId.add(acc);
            // } 

            system.debug('accountListSAMSForRemarksId' + accountListSAMSForRemarksId);

            if (acc.RecordTypeId == recordType && acc.Province_Name_SAMS__c != null) {
                accListSAMS.add(acc);
            }


            acc.SAMS_PostCode_BackUp1__c = acc.Postal_Code_SAMS__r.name;
            acc.SAMS_PostCode_BackUp2__c = acc.Zip_Postal_Code_New_SAMS__r.name;
            acc.SAMS_PostCode_BackUp3__c = acc.Zip_Postal_Code_New1_SAMS__r.name;


        }

        // Added to check that the previous License Expiry date is changed or not if it is changed the Status of the agent is N 
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {

            //Added for Producer Code Cloning
            If(Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).Producer_Code_SAMS__c != NULL && Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).Producer_Code_SAMS__c != Trigger.NewMap.get(acc.Id).Producer_Code_SAMS__c && userCheckForRole.UserRole.DeveloperName.contains('SAMS')) {
                Account clonedAccount = acc.clone(false, true, false, true);
                acc.Producer_Code_SAMS__c = Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).Producer_Code_SAMS__c;
                clonedAccount.ID_Number__c = '';
                insert clonedAccount;
            }

            //FirstName (13/8/2015)

            If((Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).First_Full_Name__c != acc.First_Full_Name__c) && (Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).FirstName == acc.FirstName)) {
                if (acc.First_Full_Name__c == null && acc.FirstName != null) {
                    acc.First_Full_Name__c = acc.FirstName;
                    //acc.addError('First Full name cannont be null');
                    // u can add error msg instead of assigning the values

                } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() > 40) {
                    acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c.subString(0, 40);
                } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() <= 40) {

                    acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c;
                }
            } else If((Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).First_Full_Name__c == acc.First_Full_Name__c) && (Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).FirstName != acc.FirstName)) {
                if (acc.First_Full_Name__c != null && acc.FirstName == null) {
                    if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() <= 40) {
                        acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c;
                        //acc.addError('First name cannont be null');
                    } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() > 40) {
                        acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c.subString(0, 40);
                        //acc.addError('First Full name cannont be null');
                    }

                } else if (acc.FirstName != null && Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).First_Full_Name__c.length() > 40) {
                    acc.addError('First name cannont be modified as the first full name more than 40 characters');

                } else if (acc.FirstName != null && Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).First_Full_Name__c.length() <= 40) {
                    acc.First_Full_Name__c = acc.FirstName;
                }

            } else If((Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).First_Full_Name__c != acc.First_Full_Name__c) && (Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.Id).FirstName != acc.FirstName)) {
                if (acc.First_Full_Name__c != null && acc.FirstName != null) {
                    if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() <= 40 && acc.First_Full_Name__c != acc.FirstName) {
                        acc.addError('First name and first full name both are less or equal 40 characters but not same');
                    } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() > 40) {
                        if (acc.FirstName != acc.First_Full_Name__c.subString(0, 40)) {
                            acc.addError('First 40 characters of first name and first full name not matching');
                        }
                    }
                } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c == null && acc.FirstName != null) {
                    acc.First_Full_Name__c = acc.FirstName;
                } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c == null && acc.FirstName == null) {
                    acc.addError('Please provide a value for First name');
                } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c != null && acc.FirstName == null) {
                    if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() <= 40) {
                        acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c;
                    } else if (acc.First_Full_Name__c.length() > 40) {
                        acc.FirstName = acc.First_Full_Name__c.subString(0, 40);
                    }

                }

            }




            //Addition ends here(13/8/2015)

            if (uniqueNationalId.contains(acc.Id_number__c) && acc.id_number__c != null && (trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).Id_number__c != acc.Id_number__c)) {
                acc.addError('The National Id for this Agent is already existis / Duplicate National Id.');


            }


            system.debug(acc.Group_Code_SAMS__c);
            system.debug(trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).Group_Code_SAMS__c);
            system.debug(acc.id);
            system.debug(mapOfAgentGroupcode.containskey(acc.id));
            //system.debug(mapOfAgentGroupcode.containskey(acc.id));
            if (acc.Group_Code_SAMS__c != null && (trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).Group_Code_SAMS__c != acc.Group_Code_SAMS__c)) {
                system.debug('inside 1st if');
                string idtest = (string.valueOf(acc.id)).substring(0, 15);
                system.debug(idtest);
                if (mapOfAgentGroupcode.containskey(idtest)) {
                    system.debug('inside 2nd if');
                    acc.addError('You are not allowed to assign this producer to another group code as it is already leader of ' + mapOfAgentGroupcode.get(idtest));
                }

            }

            /* if(acc.State_Province_New_SAMS__c != NULL){
               if(acc.State_Province_New_SAMS__r.Province_Code_SAMS__c == NULL){
                   acc.addError('State/Province of Address 2 does not has any Province Code / Invalid Province' );
               }   
           } 



             if(acc.State_Province_New1_SAMS__c != NULL){
               if(acc.State_Province_New1_SAMS__r.Province_Code_SAMS__c == NULL){
                   acc.addError('State/Province of Address 3 does not has any Province Code / Invalid Province' );
               }   
           }*/

            if (acc.RecordTypeId == recordType && acc.Province_Name_SAMS__c != null && acc.producer_code_sams__c == '') {
                accListSAMS.add(acc);
            }

            acc.SAMS_PostCode_BackUp1__c = acc.Postal_Code_SAMS__r.name;
            acc.SAMS_PostCode_BackUp2__c = acc.Zip_Postal_Code_New_SAMS__r.name;
            acc.SAMS_PostCode_BackUp3__c = acc.Zip_Postal_Code_New1_SAMS__r.name;

            if (acc.Remarks_SAMS__c != NULL) {
                acc.Remarks_SAMS__c = acc.Remarks_SAMS__c.replace('\r\n', ' ');
                acc.Remarks_SAMS__c = acc.Remarks_SAMS__c.replace('\n', ' ');
                acc.Remarks_SAMS__c = acc.Remarks_SAMS__c.replace('\r', ' ');
            }

            system.debug(acc.License_Expiry_Date_SAMS__c);
            acc.Email_Buisness_SAMS__c = acc.PersonEmail;
            system.debug(Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).License_Expiry_Date_SAMS__c);
            if (acc.License_Expiry_Date_SAMS__c != Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).License_Expiry_Date_SAMS__c) {
                acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'N';
            }
            //Added to change the account owner based on Agency Manager
            if (acc.Agency_Manager_SAMS__c != NULL && acc.Agency_Manager_SAMS__c != Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).Agency_Manager_SAMS__c) {
                acc.OwnerId = acc.Agency_Manager_SAMS__c;
            }
            // Added to genarate Contarct Number for SAMS agents                    
            if (acc.Contract_Created_SAMS__c && !trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).Contract_Created_SAMS__c)
                accountListSAMS.add(acc);
            // Added to genarate Producer Code for SAMS agents    
            if (acc.producer_code_sams__c == null && acc.HOD_Approval_SAMS__c && trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).HOD_Approval_SAMS__c == false)
                accListSAMS.add(acc);




        }
        // Agent Status assignment for SAMS 
        /* if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'Normal')
             acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'N';
        // else if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'AIG Blacklisted')
            // acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'G';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'Cancelled')
             acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'C';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'License Expired')
             acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'L';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'Dead')
             acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'D';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'Life Blacklisted')
             acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'A';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'Refer')
             acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'R';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c == 'Suspense')
             acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'S';

         if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'N')
             acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'Normal';
         //else if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'G')
            // acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'AIG Blacklisted';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'C')
             acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'Cancelled';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'L')
             acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'License Expired';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'D')
             acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'Dead';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'A')
             acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'Life Blacklisted';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'R')
             acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'Refer';
         else if(acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c != null && acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c == 'S')
             acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'Suspense';*/
        // Agent's gender assignment for SAMS
        if (acc.Gender_Expanded__c != null && acc.Gender_Expanded__c == 'Male')
            acc.Gender__c = 'M';
        else if (acc.Gender_Expanded__c != null && acc.Gender_Expanded__c == 'Female')
            acc.Gender__c = 'F';




        /* Added to check that the previous License Expiry date is changed or not 
           if it is changed and the value is greater than today means 
           expiry date of the License is a future date then the Status of the agent is N*/
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            if (acc.License_Expiry_Date_SAMS__c != Trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).License_Expiry_Date_SAMS__c && acc.License_Expiry_Date_SAMS__c > system.Today()) {
                //acc.Agent_Status_SAMS__c = 'N';
                acc.Agent_Status_Expanded_SAMS__c = 'Normal';
            }
        }
    }
    //SAMS Code Ends Here.
    //else if()
    resource = [select id, name, body from staticresource where name = : 'Territorymapping'];
    blob tempBlob = resource.Body;
    string finalString = tempBlob.toString();
    List < string > combination = finalstring.split('\n');

    for (string splitString: combination) {
        List < string > tempList = splitString.split(':', -2);
        territoryMap.put(tempList[1].toUpperCase().trim(), tempList[0].trim());
        territotyRevMap.put(tempList[0].toUpperCase().trim(), tempList[1].trim());
    }
    for (Account acc: Trigger.New) {

        if (Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate) {
            if (acc.Gender__c != null && acc.Gender__c == 'M')
                acc.Gender_Expanded__c = 'Male';
            else if (acc.Gender__c != null && acc.Gender__c == 'F')
                acc.Gender_Expanded__c = 'Female';

            if (acc.Marital_Status__c != null && acc.Marital_Status__c == 'S')
                acc.Marital_Status_Expanded__c = 'Single';
            else if (acc.Marital_Status__c != null && acc.Marital_Status__c == 'M')
                acc.Marital_Status_Expanded__c = 'Married';

            if (acc.PersonMailingState != null && territorymap.containsKey(acc.PersonMailingState.toUpperCase().Trim()) && (Trigger.isInsert || (Trigger.isUpdate && acc.personMailingState != trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).PersonMailingState))) {
                acc.Territory_Code__c = territorymap.get(acc.PersonMailingState.toUpperCase().Trim());
            }


            if (acc.Territory_Code__c != null && ((Trigger.isUpdate && acc.Territory_Code__c != trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).Territory_Code__c) || Trigger.isInsert) && territotyRevMap.containsKey(acc.Territory_Code__c)) {
                acc.PersonMailingState = territotyRevMap.get(acc.Territory_code__c);
            }


            /*Condition to check if its on insert and the producer name is null,
              change the record type to Agent/Broker */
            if (Trigger.isInsert) {
                if (acc.Agent_Broker__c != null) {
                    if (RecordTypeIDVar != null && RecordTypeIDVar.size() > 0)
                        acc.RecordTypeId = RecordTypeIDVar[0].ID;
                    acc.Type = 'Agent/Broker';
                }
            }
        }
        if (Trigger.isUpdate) {
            if (acc.Gender_Expanded__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.ID).Gender_Expanded__c) {
                if (acc.Gender_Expanded__c != null && acc.Gender_Expanded__c == 'Male')
                    acc.Gender__c = 'M';
                else if (acc.Gender_Expanded__c != null && acc.Gender_Expanded__c == 'Female')
                    acc.Gender__c = 'F';
            }
            if (acc.Marital_Status_Expanded__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(acc.ID).Marital_Status_Expanded__c)
                if (acc.Marital_Status_Expanded__c != null && acc.Marital_Status_Expanded__c == 'Married')
                    acc.Marital_Status__c = 'M';
                else if (acc.Marital_Status_Expanded__c != null && acc.Marital_Status_Expanded__c == 'Single')
                acc.Marital_Status__c = 'S';

            //Checking if the Campaign Code is changed for the Account      
            if (acc.Campaign_code__c != null && acc.Campaign_Code__c != trigger.OldMap.get(acc.id).campaign_Code__c) {
                listOfAccounts.add(acc);
                CampaignCodes.add(acc.Campaign_Code__c);
            }

        }
    }
    if (trigger.new.size() > 0) {
        Map < String, String > CampaignTypeMap = new Map < String, String > ();
        for (Campaign CampRec: [SELECT Id, type, Name, campaign_code__c FROM Campaign WHERE campaign_code__c IN: CampaignCodes]) {
            CampaignTypeMap.put(CampRec.campaign_code__c, CampRec.type);
        }
        for (Account Acc: listOfAccounts) {
            if (CampaignTypeMap.ContainsKey(Acc.Campaign_Code__c) && CampaignTypeMap.get(Acc.Campaign_Code__c) == System.Label.Campaign_Type_Acquisition)
                Acc.addError(System.Label.Account_can_only_be_associated_with_POM_Campaigns);
        }
    }

    // AccountClass has been called from here to generate Producer Code and Contrat Number for Agents 
    if (accListSAMS.size() > 0) {
        AccountClass.generateProducerCode(accListSAMS);
    } /* if(accountListSAMS.size() > 0){ AccountClass.generateContractNumber(accountListSAMS); }*/


    if (accountListSAMSForSubProducer.size() > 0) {
        System.debug('abhi:subprod');
        AccountClass.generateSubProducerCode(accountListSAMSForSubProducer);
    }

    if (accountListSAMSForAddressId.size() > 0) {
        AccountClass.generateAddressId(accountListSAMSForAddressId);

    }

    if (accountListSAMSForPhoneId.size() > 0) {
        AccountClass.generatePhoneId(accountListSAMSForPhoneId);

    }

    if (accountListSAMSForBiodataId.size() > 0) {
        AccountClass.generateBiodataId(accountListSAMSForBiodataId);

    }

    if (accountListSAMSForRemarksId.size() > 0) {
        AccountClass.generateRemarkId(accountListSAMSForRemarksId);

    }
}
```

Comment: you have to share the trigger code to help us answer you. also there are lot of existing posts related to this error in this forum which can give you the reason & best practices around this.

Comment: There can be number of possibilities. 1). Make sure you have applied correct filter in your query and you are updating only what you have to. 2). Look for any triggers on `Account` object (may be a trigger or workflow is firing).

Comment: Can you show a codes snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Your SOQL query is inside the For loop

> for(Group_Code_SAMS__c groupcode : [select Group_Code_External_Field__c,Agent_Name_Backend_Field__c from Group_Code_SAMS__c]){

And you are querying the data  from Group_Code_SAMS__c object without any condition/ where clause.

You can query the data outside the for loop:

> List < Group_Code_SAMS__c > groupcode : [select Group_Code_External_Field__c,Agent_Name_Backend_Field__c from Group_Code_SAMS__c]

Then create a Map from It if a relationship exists.

Then use this map for your processing.

It will be helpful to read Apex coding best practices. 
[Best Practices:](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code_Best_Practices) Number 1 and 2